# How do I loop through children but only as MovieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a MC with movieclips and shapes. Is there a way to loop throuh each child but only for MovieClips? I keep getting a null object because of the shape.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++) {
     var obj:MovieClip = getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
}
```

Here I thought "as MovieClip" would only trace out MovieClips...

Comment: There is no way to get only a particular type of child out of the children.  You're closer than you think, though - if <code>obj</code> is null, then it's not a MovieClip, so you can continue the loop to the next object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++) {
    if( getChildAt(i) is MovieClip ){
        var obj:MovieClip = getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
        ...
    }
}
```